# How can I count how many male/female are in each title?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am a newbie to datascience and I want to count how many female/male are in each Title.

I tried the following piece of code:

'''

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame()
newdf[ 'Title' ] = full[ 'Name' ].map( lambda name: name.split( ',' ) 
[1].split( '.' )[0].strip() )
newdf['Age'] = full['Age']
newdf['Sex'] = full['Sex']
newdf.dropna(axis = 0,inplace=True)
print(newdf.head())
```

What I get is :

```
  Title   Age     Sex
0    Mr  22.0    male
1   Mrs  38.0  female
2  Miss  26.0  female
3   Mrs  35.0  female
4    Mr  35.0    male
```

Then I am trying this to add #male,#female columns

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df = newdf[['Age','Title']].groupby('Title').mean().sort_values(by='Age',ascending=False)
df['#People'] = newdf['Title'].value_counts()
df['Male'] = newdf['Title'].sum(newdf['Sex']=='male')
df['Female'] = newdf['Title'].sum(newdf['Sex']=='female')
```

Error message that I have:
**TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed**

What I expected is to have four columns: Title,Age(average),#People, #male,#female. So I want to know how many of those #people are male and female

*P.S Without these lines :*

```
df['Male'] = newdf['Title'].sum(newdf['Sex']=='male')
df['Female'] = newdf['Title'].sum(newdf['Sex']=='female')
```

*everything works fine,and I get:*

```
    Age #People
Title       
Capt    70.000000   1
Col     54.000000   4
Sir     49.000000   1
Major   48.500000   2
Lady    48.000000   1
Dr      43.571429   7
....
```

But without #male,#female.

Comment: Note: this line is useless: `df = pd.DataFrame()`

Comment: And this: `newdf[['Age','Title']].groupby('Title')` should be rewritten as: `newdf.groupby('Title')['Age']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) for aggregate `mean` with `size` and for new columns add [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = (df.groupby('Title')['Age']
         .agg([('Age','mean'),('#People','size')])
         .sort_values(by='Age',ascending=False))

df2 = pd.crosstab(df['Title'], df['Sex']).add_suffix('_avg')

df = df1.join(df2)
print (df)
        Age  #People  female_avg  male_avg
Title                                     
Mrs    36.5        2           2         0
Mr     28.5        2           0         2
Miss   26.0        1           1         0
```

Comment: Didnt get one point. Why is is ['Age'] in df.groupby('Title')['Age'] ?

Comment: @Doctror Strange Because it is same `df = newdf[['Age','Title']].groupby('Title').mean()` - vs `newdf.groupby('Title')['Age'].mean()`.